# are rest API supported in JFrog open source free version?

Tags: jfrog-cli, jfrog-mission-control, jfrog-insights

basically I wanted to get the latestVersion of my artifact uploaded but for some reason I'm getting 404 error, though I'm able to upload files in this repo using the rest api

was thinking is this operation supported in open source jfrog(free version)

had used-

1. /api/storage/
2. /api/search/latestVersion

but both were giving 404 error

Comment: Additional information is required.
Can you specify the exact API calls used? including payload if there was any. 
404 response code means that the artifact was not found. so I believe we should focus on understanding what exactly was executed.